# How to get dynamic priority of threads in Windows NT?

Tags: c++, winapi

There does exists methods in Win32 API to get base priority of threads and processes:

> DWORD WINAPI GetPriorityClass(
>          *In*  HANDLE hProcess
>       );

&

> int WINAPI GetThreadPriority(
>         *In*  HANDLE hThread
>       );

but how can I get dynamic priority as the system may boost and lower the dynamic priority?

Comment: What do you mean by "the kernel always changes the priority of threads"?

Comment: sorry about that, I've revised my expression.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help you, but I noticed this on a patent on USPTO: _The dynamic priority of a thread is determined by adjusting a heuristic measure of the thread's execution dynamics with a priority-dependent scaling function determined from the OS priority of the thread._ . More info at [link](http://www.google.com/patents/US20010056456)

Comment: You can get it out of a WMI query, Win32_Thread.Priority property.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the static priority using `GetPriorityClass` and `GetThreadPriority`. MSDN has an article about [Scheduling Priorities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a table giving you an overview which process priority class and thread priority level result in which base priority.

I believe you are referring to [priority boosts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)!? There are functions `GetProcessPriorityBoost` and `GetThreadPriorityBoost` which give you a BOOL saying if priority boost is enabled or disabled for the process/thread. But there does not seem to be an official API to retrieve the dynamic priority (boosted).